# How to validate a pojo in play framework 2.3.x java application?

Tags: java, json, playframework, pojo, playframework-2.3

I instantiate a pojo from incoming json data. After the pojo is generated I want to validate that the pojo has all the required fields. I have marked the class using the `@Required` annotations from play, but I am not able to trigger the validation on it. Is this the correct way?

The following is my pojo from models package.

```
public class Employee
{
    @Required(message = "name is required")
    private String name;
    @Required(message = "Id is required")
    private Integer id;
}
```

In the controller class I use the following code to convert my json request to pojo

```
Employee newUser = Json.fromJson(request().body().asJson(), Employee.class);
```

Now here after this I want to validate the pojo so that the name or id is not missing from the request.

My routes has the entry

```
POST    /sayHello                   controllers.Application.sayHello()
```

How to achieve it?